# Crystal Report asking for a Database Login

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

my database is password protected. whenever I load my crystal report file using a `CrystalReportViewer` it prompts for a Database Login..

is there a way for me to eliminate this prompt? to have it automatically logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean at runtime, then [this article](https://scn.sap.com/thread/1563750) will help you

And here is the code, in case the link above is disabled:

```
    //report is just some ReportDocument.
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Tables tables = report.Database.Tables;

    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in tables)
    {
        CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo tableLogOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = "myserverIPOrHostname";
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = "MYUSER";
        tableLogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = "MYPASSWORD";

        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogOnInfo);
    }
```